# Using charts in SenchaTouch

Tags: charts, sencha-touch

I'm starting to use SenchaTouch and I like it; I would really like to be able to show interactive charts (e.g. drill-down: when the user taps a chart bar, trap the event and show another chart) in SenchaTouch apps.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already know for sure, Sencha Touch is mobile device oriented, so if you use Flash inside you iPhone / iPad mobile application it does not works.
So, I really suggest you to use [Raphaël javascript Charts](http://raphaeljs.com/).
Sencha Team already use it for the new Ext 4 release and I'm pretty use it will be even used officially on the next Sencha Touch release.

I post you a simple exampe that show you how to initialize a Raphael Chart inside a Panel body:

```
var myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
fullscreen: true,
html: 'The tabs above are also sortable.<br />(tap and hold)<br/>' +
    '<div id="raphaelChart"></div>',
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(){
        //Let's create the Raphael chart
        var set = Raphael(['raphaelChart', 320, 200, {
            type: "rect",
            x: 10,
            y: 10,
            width: 25,
            height: 25,
            stroke: "#f00"
        },{
            type: "text",
            x: 70,
            y: 50,
            text: "This is a Raphael Example"
        }]);
    }
}
```

});

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the Open flash Chart http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/

these are very easy to use and interactive.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

http://code.google.com/p/oppo-touching/

this is making the charts in Ext JS 4 available for Sencha Touch!